# ORG-REF: Indicate just path where to search for bib files?

Tags: org-mode, org-ref

I know that one should indicate the bib files for org-ref. I happen to have a huge amount of bib files (exported from Mendeley for each Mendeley folder).

My question: Is it possible to just indicate the path instead of every bib file?

```
(setq org-ref-default-bibliography '("~/Dropbox/Bib/"))
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this to add all the .bib files in that directory:

```
(require 'f)
(setq org-ref-default-bibliography (f-files "~/Dropbox/Bib" (lambda (f) (f-ext? f "bib"))))
```

Comment: Thank you. I guess I have to do the same for  (setq helm-bibtex-bibliography '("~/Dropbox/Bib"))? Another issue I noticed now is that it is not loading all entries, just a few hundred.

Comment: There is a built-in and significantly more efficient way of doing the exact same thing: `(directory-files "~/Dropbox/Bib" t "\\.bib\\'")`. See the documentation for functions `directory-files` and `directory-files-recursively`.